# AS3: Fast hovering doesn't execute rollOut

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, button

I'm having a serious problem that is getting me nervous:

I've made a button *_btn* that includes ROLLOVER and ROLLOUT animations with coding (an nested movieclip instance called *barra* that increases to half alpha when you hover over and decreases when you hover out).

[*Here it should go a descriptive image but I'm new and I need 10 reputation. I'll appreciate your help*]

This works perfectly but **the problem occurs when I move my cursor very quickly from one point to another, with the button in between**. It seems that the ROLLOUT function is not detected, so the ROLLOVER animation keeps working (and if you look carefully, the animation stops for a few seconds and then continues).

[*Here it should go another descriptive image too*]

This is the code in the Actions layer:

```
//Funciones ROLL OVER
function _btnOver(event:MouseEvent):void {
    _btn.buttonMode = true;
    _btn.addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME,_btnFadeIn);
}

function _btnFadeIn(event:Event):void {
    _btn.barra.alpha += 0.1;
    if (_btn.barra.alpha >= 0.5)
    {
    _btn.removeEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME,_btnFadeIn);
    }
}

_btn.addEventListener(MouseEvent.ROLL_OVER,_btnOver);


//Funciones ROLL OUT
function _btnOut(event:MouseEvent):void {
_btn.addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME,_btnFadeOut);
}

function _btnFadeOut(event:Event):void {
    _btn.barra.alpha -= 0.1;
    if (_btn.barra.alpha <= 0.2)
    {
    _btn.removeEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME,_btnFadeOut);
    }
}

_btn.addEventListener(MouseEvent.ROLL_OUT,_btnOut);
```

[Click here if you  want to download the FLA and SWF files](https://drive.google.com/folderview?id=0B_JvcV9KvSNQfmh0SVV6WjVJODFIdW5VVDR2bVZrTkQ0Zkhyb2VKOXgxYnJ5M2F5SjJ5dnM&usp=sharing), so you can see the problem clearly.

I barely know how to use ActionScript 3 (my only programming knowledge is Processing) and I don't have time now to learn it from head to toe, but I've researched about the problem and it's still not clear.

With tutorials and guides, I managed to learn how to create and understand this code, and **I think the problem might be in the functions of the events ROLL_OVER and ROLL_OUT, which contain the addEventListener of the ENTER_FRAME events (where the animations actually are), respectively**. But I don't know exactly what I have to do to fix it, what should I add or change.

I would be really glad if someone could help with this, I'm frustrated! What do you recommend me to do?

Thanks in advance

(PD: I don't understand most of the programming language. If you can be as clear and direct as possible, I'll really appreciate it)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I edited some code in here, basically i am checking hover state onLoop function, so you can change your settings on here

```
import flash.events.Event;

var isRolledOver:Boolean = false;

//Funciones ROLL OVER
function _btnOver(event:MouseEvent):void {
    isRolledOver = true;
}

function _btnOut(event:MouseEvent):void {
    isRolledOver = false;
}

_btn.addEventListener(MouseEvent.ROLL_OVER,_btnOver);

_btn.addEventListener(MouseEvent.ROLL_OUT,_btnOut);

this.addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME,onLoop);

function onLoop(e){
    if(this.isRolledOver){
        if(_btn.barra.alpha < 0.5) _btn.barra.alpha += 0.1;
    }
    else{
        if(_btn.barra.alpha > 0.5 || _btn.barra.alpha > 0) _btn.barra.alpha -= 0.1;
    }
}
```

I added the sample [fla](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/53894534/ejemplo.fla) in case

Comment: `if(_btn.barra.alpha > 0.5 || _btn.barra.alpha > 0)` === `if(_btn.barra.alpha > 0)`, and, if you'd look at OP's code, he has fadeout threshold at 0.2.

Comment: Thanks for the help and time Özgür! I can see now how could I take advantage of variables instead of the "enterframe" listeners, which I still barely understand.

Answer (score 1):

Apparently your troubles lay in incoherent animation sequence by using enter frame listeners. You are running two independent listeners, both altering `alpha` of a single object, this creates a conflict, only one will work (you can determine which if you add both at once and trigger events, the resultant alpha value will indicate which listener changes it last) and you apparently expect one to do a fade in while the other to do a fade out. Instead, you should use one listener (probably even persistent) and give your object "target alpha" property as well as delta to change alpha per frame. An example:

```
var bbta:Number=0.2; // btn.barra's target alpha
_btn.addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME,_btnFade);
function _btnFade(e:Event):void {
    var a:Number=_btn.barra.alpha;
    if (Math.abs(a-bbta)<1e-8) return; 
    // no sense of setting alpha with minuscule difference
    const delta:Number=0.1; // how fast to change per frame
    if (a>bbta) {
        a-=delta;
        if (a<=bbta) a=bbta;
    } else {
        a+=delta;
        if (a>=bbta) a=bbta;
    }
    _btn.barra.alpha=a;
}
function _btnOver(event:MouseEvent):void {
    _btn.buttonMode = true; // move this elsewhere, if you don't cancel buttonMode
    bbta=0.5; // set target alpha, the listener will do a fade-in
}
function _btnOut(event:MouseEvent):void {
    bbta=0.2; // set target alpha, the listener will do a fade-out
}
```

Comment: Thanks Vesper, I  thought I had to make a listener for each change of alpha, but what you say seems more coherent. I guess I'll have to read a bit more about listeners and functions.